# Rowspan using Meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

My purpose is to display a table with the leftmost column containing course title at a college, and the rest of the row information regarding textbooks to that course.

This is what it looks like now:
[current table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xn61U.png)

Here is an image of what I would like to happen:
[Textbook information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMC7r.png)

Here is my code for what I have now.

```
{{#each getCourses}}
<tr>
   <td>{{this}}</td>
   {{#each getTextbooks this}}
   <td>                    
      {{title}}
      <br>                     
   </td>
   <td>Editor</td>
   <td><span class="label label-success">Active</span>
   </td>
   <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">I have it</button> </td>
   <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">I want it</button> </td>
   {{/each}}                          
</tr>
{{/each}}
```

Before this table, a user is able to select several courses from a dropdown, and then I store the courses in a session and get them and iterate. Each course has textbooks, so I iterate over the list of textbooks. However the problem I face is that I'm not sure how to incorporate rowspan or something like that to allow multiple rows of textbook information for each class.

Comment: Well, you can determine how many books you have per course... you can use that count to set the rowspan value.

Comment: Sorry I know that finding the size and making the rowspan equal to that size will give me the space to have multiple sub-rows of textbooks, but  Im not sure how to connect that in order to display each textbook on its on row. Do I need to change something inside or right before the {{#each}} for the textbooks?

Comment: Hi, I decided not to use a table and am instead using the grid system in bootstrap. Thank you however!